# Are these songs from "My Little Pony: Friendship is Magic"?

Tags: my-little-pony-fim, my-little-pony

Are these songs from "My Little Pony: Friendship is Magic"?

Comment: It does not seem to be....

Answer (score 3):

### Unlikely

These both seem to be fan productions, with songs taken from other sources.

The first song is “[Come Little Children](https://disney.wikia.com/wiki/Come_Little_Children),” from the film *Hocus Pocus* (1993). This is shown in the credits:

[image: Credits mentioning "Come Little Children"]

The singer is not any one of the actors who voiced Princess Luna, as seen [here](https://www.behindthevoiceactors.com/characters/My-Little-Pony/Princess-Luna/).

The second song appears to be something called “[Daylight’s End](http://lyrics.wikia.com/wiki/Lisa_Thorn:Daylight%27s_End)” from *League of Legends*.

[image: Credits mentioning the second song]

The songs were presumably chosen because they made good theme music for the fan animations centered around Princess Luna.